# Postfix Relay Based on Sender Recepient

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, email-server

What is the best practice when one has to implement this sort of ruleset in postfix:

- Email sent from local domain1.com, domain2.com to example.com, example1.com ought to be relayed to smtp.external.com.
- Email sent to everyone else example.com and example1.com ought to be relayed locally

I know there is a way to do a relay filtering recipient address using transport_maps, but I do not know how to filter depending on the sender address too.

Can you help me please?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To choose the relay based on sender address, have a look into Postfix [sender_dependent_relayhost_maps](http://www.kmz.co.za/blog/getting-postfix-to-support-relaying-based-on-sender-address/).

Comment: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps is used to filter mail senders, but I want to filter both senders and receivers at the same time. With a certain incoming mail and outgoing mail, filter using an external relay.

Comment: Not sure you can have it both ways. Would running two postfix instances help? Maybe you could use the second instance as a next hop for the first instance. On the first instance apply transport_maps filtering, and on the second apply sender_dependent_relayhost_maps?